# Give a default value for fields not available in json using aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am trying to load json using the Aeson library. The thing is that the datastructure that I want to load it into contains more fields than the json.

```
data Resource = Res {
                  name :: String,
                  file :: FilePath,
                  res :: Picture,
                  loaded :: Bool
                } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

Where only the name and the file fields are available in the json. Picture is a gloss Picture so that can't really be loaded from json.

I can't figure out how to leave out res and loaded out of the FromJSON instance.

Comment: Where _is_ that information supposed to come from, if not from the JSON input?

Comment: The picture is loaded later, after reading the json, and at that time the loaded field will be set as well. I guess a loaded could be false by default, but the question remains how to do that.

Comment: But then what should the value of `res` be, when the picture is not loaded? Since this isn't java it can't be `null`, it has to be a picture. If want it to be able to be `null` you have to change the type to `Maybe Picture`.

Comment: I guess I could try that, same for loaded. Make them both Maybe

Comment: Defining res as Maybe Picture still gives an error: No instance for (FromJSON Picture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't load that structure from JSON, then don't define it this way! Make it

```
data ResourceRef = ResRef
                { name :: String
                , file :: FilePath
                } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

That can be easily loaded from JSON. You can then have an additional

```
data Resource = Res
                { resName :: String
                , resFile :: FilePath
                , res :: Picture
                } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

...which never gets in contact with JSON. And implement

```
loadResource :: ResourceRef -> IO Resource
```

Comment: Just 33 seconds before I wrote basically the same answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I pretty much ended up doing something like this indeed

Comment: Could I ask a follow up question though? Because currently how I read the file contents is a mess because the regular readFile doesn't output a ByteString. How could I fix that?