# How to use Parsers from Aeson with IO

Tags: haskell, parsec, aeson

I have data types with many fields that, if not being manually specified by a JSON configuration file, should be randomly set. I am using Aeson to parse the config file. What is the best way to do this?

Currently, I am setting values equal to some impossible value, and then later checking for said value to edit.

```
data Example = Example { a :: Int, b :: Int }
default = Example 1 2
instance FromJSON Example where
    parseJSON = withObject "Example" $ \v -> Example
      <$> (v .: "a" <|> return (a default)) 
      <*> (v .: "b" <|> return (b default))

initExample :: Range -> Example -> IO Example
initExample range (Example x y) = do
   a' <- if x == (a default) then randomIO range else return x
   b' <- if y == (b default) then randomIO range else return y
   return $ Example a' b'
```

What I would like is something along the lines of:

```
parseJSON = withObject "Example" $ \v -> Example
      <$> (v .: "a" <|> return (randomRIO (1,10))
```

Is it possible to define Parsers in the IO Monad or thread along some random generator, ideally using Aeson?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it's a good idea, and juggling the extra `IO` layer will certainly get frustrating as heck for larger developments, but the following type-checks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Aeson
import System.Random

data Example = Example { a :: Int, b :: Int } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance FromJSON (IO Example) where
    parseJSON = withObject "Example" $ \v -> liftA2 Example
        <$> ((pure <$> (v .: "a")) <|> pure (randomRIO (3, 4)))
        <*> ((pure <$> (v .: "b")) <|> pure (randomRIO (5, 6)))
```

In each of the last two lines, the first `pure` is `Int -> IO Int`, and the second is `IO Int -> Parser (IO Int)`. In ghci:

```
> sequence (decode "{}") :: IO (Maybe Example)
Just (Example {a = 4, b = 6})
```

Comment: As mentioned by @danidiaz, this is essentially using the `Applicative` and `Alternative` instances for `Compose Parser IO`. One could either use that type directly, or use it as further guidance for writing such code in larger developments.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a good strategy to get where you want to be since the ParseJSON monad is not a transformer or based on IO.  What you can more easily do is decode into one type then translate into the second as done in a prior question '[Give a default value for fields not available in json using aeson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810998/give-a-default-value-for-fields-not-available-in-json-using-aeson)'.

Since large structures can be cumbersome to reproduce you could make the structure parameterized and instantiate it with either `IO Int` or `Int`.  For example, let's say you wanted field `a` from the wire but `b` as random from the IO monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

import Data.Aeson
import System.Random
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)

data Example' a =
        Example { a :: Int
                , b :: a
                } deriving (Show,Functor,Foldable,Traversable)

type Partial = Example' (IO Int)

type Example = Example' Int

instance FromJSON Partial where
    parseJSON (Object o) =
        Example <$> o .: "a"
                <*> pure (randomRIO (1,10))

loadExample :: Partial -> IO Example
loadExample = mapM id

parseExample :: ByteString -> IO (Maybe Example)
parseExample = maybe (pure Nothing) (fmap Just . loadExample) . decode
```

Notice how `loadExample` uses our `traverse` instance to execute the IO actions inside the structure.  Here is an example use:

```
Main> parseExample "{ \"a\" : 1111 }"
Just (Example {a = 1111, b = 5})
```

**Advanced**

If you had more than one type of field for which you wanted an IO action you could either

1. Make one data type for all of them.  Instead of `b` being type `IO Int` you might make it `IO MyComplexRecord`.  This is the easy solution.
2. The more complex and fun solution is to use a higher kind type parameter.

For option 2, consider:

```
 data Example' f = Example { a :: Int
                           , b :: f Int
                           , c :: f String }
```

You could then use `Proxy` and `Control.Monad.Identity` instead of values like `IO Int` and `Int` used previously.  You'll need to write your own traversal since you can't derive `Traverse` for this class (which is what gives us the `mapM` used above).  We could make a traversal class with kind `(* -> *) -> *` using a few extensions (RankNTypes among them) but unless this is done often, and we get some sort of deriving support or TH, I don't think that is worthwhile.

Comment: `the ParseJSON monad is not a transformer or based on IO`. But it's an `Applicative` though, and `Applicative`s compose. Perhaps a solution based on `Data.Functor.Compose IO Parser` could work.

Comment: Sure, I'd love to see that answer too.

Comment: @danidiaz In fact in my answer I use only `Applicative` combinators, and am essentially using the `Compose` instances (but without the `Compose` newtype wrapper). But I didn't realize it until you pointed it out, so that's a nice insight and guide for writing the code in a larger development!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, it involves a bit more manual labour, but the approach is quite straightforward - generate a random `IO Example` use it to generate a random "parser". Decoding into JSON is done with the usual `decode` function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Test where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import System.Random

data Example = Example {_a :: Int, _b :: Int} deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

getExample :: IO (Value -> Maybe Example)
getExample = do
 ex <- randomRIO (Example 1 1, Example 10 100)
 let ex' = withObject "Example" $ \o ->
             do a <- o .:? "a" .!= _a ex
                b <- o .:? "b" .!= _b ex
                return $ Example a b
 return (parseMaybe ex')

instance Random Example where
    randomRIO (low,hi) = Example <$> randomRIO (_a low,_a hi)
                                 <*> randomRIO (_b low,_b hi)
...

main :: IO ()
main = do
    getExample' <- getExample
    let example = getExample' =<< decode "{\"a\": 20}"
    print example
```

I am not sure but I believe this is the more verbose implementation of @DanielWagner's solution.

Comment: re: "I believe this is the more verbose implementation of @DanielWagner's solution", I think our approaches are slightly different (though both interesting); you do some `IO` to generate a parser, while I do some parsing to generate an `IO` action.

Comment: That's an interesting way to break it down. We have three answers that boil down to "Parse and generate an IO action needed executed", "Execute IO to generate a parser", and "Parse to generate an object with embedded IO actions for execution".