# Lifting the parser of a large record type into a functor

Tags: haskell

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46820379/371228) about parsing JSON within a monadic context.

Consider a simple record type and its [Data.Aeson.FromJSON](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON) instance. For the `(Int, Int)` field, I’m reading one value from the JSON and setting the other to 20.

```
import Data.Aeson

data DataPoint = DataPoint { placeName :: String
                           , readings :: (Int, Int)
                           } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON DataPoint where
    parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o -> DataPoint
        <$> o .: "name"
        <*> fmap (\v -> (v, 20)) (o .: "reading")
```

This works fine:

```
> (decodeThrow "{\"name\": \"Greenland\", \"reading\": 54}") :: Maybe DataPoint
Just (DataPoint {placeName = "Greenland", readings = (54,20)})
```

I'd like to replace that dummy 20 with a value that's provided separately. Following [Daniel Wagner’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46821125/371228), I can lift this into the [reader monad](https://hackernoon.com/the-reader-monad-part-1-1e4d947983a8)/[environment functor](https://blog.plover.com/prog/haskell/evaluation-functor.html) `(->) Int` like

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)

instance FromJSON (Int -> DataPoint) where
    parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o -> liftA2 DataPoint
        <$> fmap pure             (o .: "name")
        <*> fmap (\v c -> (v, c)) (o .: "reading")
```

In GHCi,

```
> let f = (decodeThrow "{\"name\": \"Greenland\", \"reading\": 54}") :: Maybe (Int -> DataPoint)
> f <*> Just 7
Just (DataPoint {placeName = "Greenland", readings = (54,7)})
```

In this case, `liftA2`, which has type

```
liftA2 :: Functor f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

is specialized to

```
liftA2 :: (Parser String -> Parser (Int, Int) -> Parser DataPoint)
    -> (Int -> Parser String)
    -> (Int -> Parser (Int, Int))
    -> (Int -> Parser DataPoint)
```

Here’s my problem. My real record has something like seven fields, so I would have to write a function like `liftA7` to be able to use this same approach with my real data. This is easy enough, but the fact that the standard library only provides `liftA`, `liftA2`, and `liftA3` makes me think that I should be using a different approach to lift my parser into the `(->) Int` functor. Is there a better approach? Or do I need to just write out `liftA7` and use that?

Comment: Looks like maybe you need `Data.Functor.Compose`, so you can use normal applicative syntax with a 2-layered functor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to lift through nested contexts here. The type `parseJSON :: Parser (Int -> DataPoint)` is simply asking you to write a `Parser` which returns a function.

Looking at your original code,

```
parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o -> DataPoint
    <$> o .: "name"
    <*> fmap (\v -> (v, 20)) (o .: "reading")
```

I notice first of all that you're using a nested `fmap` underneath a `<*>` call. I'm going to reassociate this (the legality of this is [a consequence of the applicative laws](https://gist.github.com/benjamin-hodgson/5b36259986055d32adea56d0a7fa688f)) to simplify your code:

```
parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o ->
    (\name reading -> DataPoint name (reading, 20))
    <$> o .: "name"
    <*> o .: "reading"
```

This is easier to read overall, in my opinion. I'm just applying a two-argument function to two arguments in a context.

Now hopefully you can see how to make this parser return an `Int -> DataPoint` - just change the return type of the function you're mapping over the arguments.

```
parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o ->
    (\name reading -> \x -> DataPoint name (reading, x))
    <$> o .: "name"
    <*> o .: "reading"
```

As a syntactic nicety, Haskell allows you to flatten nested lambdas.

```
parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o ->
    (\name reading x -> DataPoint name (reading, x))
    <$> o .: "name"
    <*> o .: "reading"
```

And by the way, this is all equivalent to the noisier-but-perhaps-more-legible `do`-notation:

```
parseJSON = withObject "DataPoint" $ \o -> do
    name <- o .: "name"
    reading <- o .: "reading
    return $ \x -> DataPoint name (reading, x)
```

A quick test:

```
main = 
    let input = "{\"name\": \"Greenland\", \"reading\": 54}"
        f = decode input :: Maybe (Int -> DataPoint)
    in print $ fmap ($ 7) f
-- Just (DataPoint {placeName = "Greenland", readings = (7,54)})
```

Comment: Could you expand on how the applicative laws allow you to float the `fmap (\v -> (v,20))` up to the "top"?

Comment: @chepner [it's a little tedious to do it by hand](https://gist.github.com/benjamin-hodgson/5b36259986055d32adea56d0a7fa688f) but intuitively `fmap` doesn't perform any effects so you're free to move it around as you like

Comment: Thanks. Definitely not obvious :) I think it's worth adding as an appendix to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I’ve taken this approach and written a blog post around it: https://esham.io/2019/03/parsing-json-with-more-context Thank you again for sharing this technique here!

Comment: Happy to help! ❤️